# UILabel with Image and text in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, image, text, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I am making UILabel with Image and text inside that.I try many thing like below.

**Try 1 :**

Using this code

```
var textAttchment = new NSTextAttachment();
textAttchment.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("location_grey_icon");
var attachmentString = NSAttributedString.FromAttachment(textAttchment);
var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(lbl_inr.Text.ToString());
this.lbl_inr.AttributedText = attributedString;
```

But it only display the Text not the image.

**Try 2:**

using this code

```
var attchment = new NSTextAttachment();
attchment.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("location_grey_icon");
attchment.Bounds = new CGRect(0, -1, 13, 13);
var intiliazeText = this.text_inr.AttributedText;
var newText = new NSMutableAttributedString(intiliazeText);
newText.Append(NSAttributedString.CreateFrom(attchment));
this.text_inr.AttributedText = newText;
```

it is display the Image and Text both.

**Output :**

[image]

**What I want :**

but my requirement is to I want to set image before the Text so first Image and then Text.

Any help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is very specific, the best way to do this would be with a custom control.

UIView + Label + UIImageView

and there you could set your bounds to your needs. With the designer this is a simple task.

Or you could try with a UITextField, removing the borders and disabling it. Then adding a UIImageView as the RightView (or LeftView as you wish).

```
var textEdit = new UITextField (new CGRect (15, 100, 200, 30));
textEdit.Enabled = false;

textEdit.Text = "Hello from Xamarin";
var xamImageView = new UIImageView (new CGRect (0,0, 25, 25));
xamImageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("xamagon");
textEdit.RightView = xamImageView;
textEdit.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
textEdit.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
textEdit.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
```

**Result:**

[image: results]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks But I want to do this only with one `UILabel` but thanks anyway.

Comment: see my answer I am perform that using one single `UILabel`.

Comment: @Ironman When you said "but my requirement is to I want to set image before the Text so first Image and then Text." I understood something different. Good you found the way.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Using below code I manage

```
var attchment = new NSTextAttachment();
attchment.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("location_grey_icon");
attchment.Bounds = new CGRect(0, -2, 14, 14);
var newText = new NSMutableAttributedString();
newText.Append(NSAttributedString.CreateFrom(attchment));
NSAttributedString s = new NSAttributedString(item.Total.ToString());
newText.Append(s);
this.lbl_inr.AttributedText = newText;
```

**Output :**

[image]